# Error with Python sleep() command on http://rept.it

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, runtime-error, sleep

I'm working on a project involving the `sleep()` command, (running 2.7.2) and it's throwing errors that I've never seen before. Here's a test script I wrote:

```
from time import sleep

print '1'
sleep(2)
print '2'
```

It returns:

```
>> 1
>> Internal error: ReferenceError: _select is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What platform are you running this on?

Comment: Something about your Python install is broken. You'll have to give us as much information as possible about your setup and how you are running the script, as noone else will be able to replicate this themselves.

Comment: All the google hits I get on this error seem to involve online REPLs - are you using a REPL on the internet, or on your local machine?

Comment: yes...see my comment on gnibbler's answer below

Answer (score 2):

time.sleep() uses `select` if it is available. For some reason `HAVE_SELECT` was defined when your Python was built, but now the library can't be found.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

> ...
>   On the other hand, the precision of time() and sleep() is better
>   than their Unix equivalents: times are expressed as floating point
>   numbers, time() returns the most accurate time available (using Unix
>   gettimeofday() where available), and sleep() will accept a time with a
>   nonzero fraction (Unix select() is used to implement this, where
>   available).
>   ...

From the source:

```
floatsleep(double secs)
{
/* XXX Should test for MS_WINDOWS first! */
#if defined(HAVE_SELECT) && !defined(__BEOS__) && !defined(__EMX__)
    struct timeval t;
    double frac;
    frac = fmod(secs, 1.0);
    secs = floor(secs);
    t.tv_sec = (long)secs;
    t.tv_usec = (long)(frac*1000000.0);
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    if (select(0, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, &t) != 0) {
#ifdef EINTR
...
```

Could be that your Python was compiled for a different environment to where it is running.

Where did your Python come from? How was it compiled?

Comment: I did see that section of the docs, but failed to understand it. I'm running 2.7.2 on an online interpreter-[repl.it](http://repl.it) only because it's more convenient than downloading an interpreter. Am I to assume that this error is on the end of those running the site?

Comment: repl.it actually runs the interpreter on your browser, so I'd say it's either a bug in emscriptem, or the build script is erroneously setting that define when it shouldn't be. You could check if repl.it already knows about this bug, or file a ticket about it.