# Trying to delay in python

Tags: python, delay

I try to add a delay in my code (Im using python v 2.7.2), like this:

```
import time
time.sleep(2)
print "Hi"
```

But this error pops up:

```
Internal error: ReferenceError: _select is not defined
```

Please help, this would really make my code much cooler :)

Comment: hi there.. please check this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275828/error-with-python-sleep-command-on-http-rept-it) as this may help you

Comment: Where did you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

This error is a result of you running your code in CodeAcademy Labs. It appears from some research this error happens when you are compiling on a different system than the actual interpreter is run on, for some reason.

If you can, run your program on a Python install on your actual system instead of one online and it should work as it did for me.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Have you tried with an actual installation of Python?